# programacion en wordpress como backend

Tags: php, wordpress, backend

estoy comenzando a utilizar wordpress como backend y estoy teniendo algunos problemas con diseño, por ejemplo... necesito un apartado donde poner una url y que el front se visualiza un video de youtube, tambien necesito "categorías" como, tamaño, calidad, duración... y no se de que forma hacerlo ya que wordpress no me permite añadir estos apartados individualmente, ¿tendría que hacer el código una a uno en cada entrada de wordpress?

http://prntscr.com/vf4hmu
necesito algo como esto, tema titulos tags y contenidos lo tengo sulicionado pero de que forma puedo añadir en una casilla un link de youtube y que en el front reemplaze

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x73-573aWfs" frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

esto por el link que yo le dé, al igual que las casillas de fecha,tamaño,calidad,duracion ect.

Answer (score 0):

aunque esto es posible de manera nativa usando el functions.php de tu tema, es un proceso algo complejo y laborioso, mas que todo laborioso, si es para tus clientes, lo recomendable no es hacerlo desde cero, para eso se usan complementos de campos personalizar, te recomiendo Awesome Custom Fields, es el mejor que existe actualmente y te permitira utilizar una gran variedad de Campos, en su sitio web encontraras el plugin y la documentacion para usarlo.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

La version gratuita basta para hacer cosas increibles, pero la version premium tiene opciones como los repeater.